# Declaration of 'RCTDirectEventBlock' must be imported from module 'RNFirebase.BannerComponent' before it is required

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm encountering an issue when building my React Native project with Xcode 15, using react-native version 0.61.2 and react-native-firebase version 5.0.0. The error message I'm seeing is:

`Declaration of 'RCTDirectEventBlock' must be imported from module 'RNFirebase.BannerComponent' before it is required`.

This issue occurs specifically when building the project for the simulator.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Use Xcode 15
2. Include react-native version 0.61.2 in the project.
3. Include react-native-firebase version 5.0.0.
4. Attempt to build the project for the simulator.
5. Additional Information:

- Xcode Version: 15
- React Native Version: 0.61.2
- React Native Firebase Version: 5.0.0
- Code Snippets:
  [image]
  My AppDelegate:
  [image]
  Error Message: [image]

Attempted Solutions:
I have tried with Go to Xcode -> Settings -> Locations -> Derived Data -> Click on the right arrow icon Delete the Derived data folder and run again. But it not working

Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.